# How do I POST a x-www-form-urlencoded request using Fetch AND work with the answer?

Tags: javascript, fetch, x-www-form-urlencoded

this is my code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    'size': 'size_id',
    'style': 'style_id',
    'qty': '1'
  })
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });
```

My problem is that I just get 'Promise pending' returned.
Im totaly new to fetch and really new to js, so please dont blame me.

Answer (score 4):

`res` is the [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), not the response data.

Are you expecting json? Then do:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    'size': 'size_id',
    'style': 'style_id',
    'qty': '1'
  })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });
```

otherwise get the plain response data/text like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    'size': 'size_id',
    'style': 'style_id',
    'qty': '1'
  })
})
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });
```

Comment: I follow your code with my own url (it’s work when I call by postman), but this result: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: res is not defined